# Typo3 4.5 TCA BackEnd Form Ajax Updater: Categories for Keywords

Tags: ajax, typo3, backend

I would like to add a dropdown box (displaying categories for keywords) with onchange event. The onchange event should update the keyword list in my backend form. How to do this? Any hint very much welcome!

```
"keywordCategories" => Array (
"exclude" => 1,
"l10n_mode" => "mergeIfNotBlank",
"label" => "Categories",
"config" => Array (
            "type" => "select",
            "foreign_table" => "my_extension_categories",
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at extension [tagpack](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/tagpack) perhaps it is usefull as a starting point, how to implement that stuff.